# google search api results not same as google search

Tags: python, api, google-custom-search

i am using google search api to search in python, however the results the api generates are different from the one using google search on a browser.
How to get the same result as google search through api?
i have to use api strictly as it avoids ip blocking.

tried requests and urllib for the same but ip gets blocked after some time so api is only option.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

my_api_key = "my api key"
my_cse_id = "my cse id"

def google_search(search_term, api_key, cse_id, **kwargs):
    service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=api_key)
    res = service.cse().list(q=search_term, cx=cse_id, **kwargs).execute()
    return res


results = google_search(
    "keyword to search", my_api_key, my_cse_id, num=10)
print(results)
```

Comment: When you use your browser to search something in google, the results will be highly personalized based on your location, history, search context, etc. This may not be the same case with an API. May I ask why do you need the same results using the API?

Comment: because search results from browsers are more relevant to my needs.what i get from api is neither accurate and nor up to date.